# Visualize Cronbach's alpha in R Ggplot scatterplot as a regression line?

Tags: r, scatterplot, ggplot2, cronbachs-alpha

I'm looking for a way to make a scatterplot of the correlation between two questionnaires using Cronbach's alpha:

Data:

```
measurements <- matrix(c(2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                         0, 0, -1, -2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                         0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2), nrow = 50, ncol = 2, byrow = T)
colnames(measurements) = c("questionnaire_1", "questionnaire_2")
measurements <- as.matrix(measurements)
measurements <- as.data.frame(measurements)
```

I get alpha = 0.83 (95% CI 0.66-0.93) using this code:

```
cronbach.alpha(measurements, standardized = F, CI = T, na.rm = T)
```

However, I would also like to visualize this in scatter plot.

I've found a way to do this with Spearman's correlation:

```
measurements_n <- measurements %>%
  group_by(questionnaire_1, questionnaire_2) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(
  measurements_n, aes(x=questionnaire_1, y=questionnaire_2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = n)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), color = "white") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(4, 15)) +
  sm_statCorr(data = measurements_n, aes(x=questionnaire_1, y=questionnaire_2), 
              color = "#EE6677", corr_method = "spearman", fullrange = T) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2, 2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-2, 2)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown(), plot.caption = element_markdown(),
        axis.title.x = element_markdown(), axis.title.y = element_markdown()) +
  guides(size = guide_legend("Observations")) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = "on", expand = T)
```

[image: scatterplot_spearman]

However, is there a way to do this with Cronbach's alpha instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see how it would make a lot of sense to depict Cronbach's alpha in this way. Cronbach's alpha is a measure of composite reliability (reliability of the aggregate/sum score of the two questionnaires combined). As such, it indicates the squared correlation (R-squared) between the composite (aggregate/sum score of the two questionnaires) and the underlying latent true score variable. To depict the correlation between your aggregate/sum score and the underlying true scores, you would have to estimate the scores on the true score variable in some way (e.g., by estimating factor scores through confirmatory factor analysis), which is typically not a very fruitful endeavor.

Comment: Thank you Christian for your clear and helpful explanation. It helped us to learn more about the method, and we may reconsider our choice. Thank you!